# How do I set an image to my imageView without the imagePickerController hiding it?

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, uiimagepickercontroller

Ideally I'm looking to set the image returned from my camera to an imageView, but without dismissing the controller so it seamlessley fills the screen. Below is my code: I am setting the image property that is returned to my image view after dismissing the imagepickercontroller - how do I set this so the image sets to the image view over the imagepickercontrooler without having to dismiss the imagepickercontroller. Ideally I'd like the image to set to the imageView and for my VC to display that without having to dismiss the imagepicker. Cheers

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let IMG: UIImage  = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in
        imageArray.append(IMG)
        self.imageView0.image = IMG

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: `self.imageView0.image = IMG`
If you want to save image also in array try this way:

```
imageArray.append(IMG)
```

but do not use this inside `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

Comment: thanks mate, thats great. Any clues how to now make that imageView fill the screen. at the moment it only fills a portion of it and isnt constrained to the edges of the screen.

Comment: lets imagine that you need imageView on the top of Left corner with size of 150x150. 

imageView0.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)
imageView0.ContentMode = .ScaleToFill

but i don't understand you need imageView with scaleToFill image or imageView on the full screen?

Comment: I want the image that is set to my imageview to fill the whole screen (snapchat esq). Does the above code achieve that?

Comment: imageView0.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height)

imageView will be all over the screen. if you need to give it some transparency you can write this imageView0.alpha = 0.7  . If Helped Please Accept answer

Comment: could I ask one more question. Do you know how to make the imagepickercontroller fill the screen. This is my code:
  imagePicker.sourceType = 

UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
        imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: nil)

Comment: if you have already opened question about it link it and i will write answer

Comment: I have hidden the camera controls but there is just a big black space. How do I fill that with extra imagePickerControlleR?

Comment: i will post it now. one sec

Comment: I have to wait a bit because can't post questions within 90mins of each other. I will post the question in about an hour and link it to you. Thanks brother

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223881/how-do-i-fill-the-whole-screen-with-my-imagepicker here you go